# How does an Arabic web browser work

Tags: dns, browser, web

How are fonts rendered and defined in a web browser for a language that is written right to left (such as Arabic)?

Does the browser switch the direction of domain names (the URL) or do they stay the same?

Comment: I am guessing that the URL is the same because I doubt very much any one on the design board cared to think about right to left at the time of drafting the protocol. However; [internationalized domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does a web browser in a language that is written right to
>   left(like Arabic) work?

Browsers simply render the **HTML** information, and there are tags that specify the browser in which direction they should render the text.

HTML below would specify the browser to render text from **Right to Left**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

> Does the browser switch the direction of domain names and the url or
>   does is stay the same?

Also *Domain names/URL* stay in the same format i.e. **www.some-arabic-site.com**

[image]

Because they all use the same **protocol** to communicate over internet & they all use same DNS query method to resolve names over internet

Comment: Internationalized domain names (IDNs) are encoded in DNS using Punycode - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode - but the browser will render the domain in your browser's address bar according to your locally set language.

Comment: @LawrenceC does this mean some punycode domains go right to left instead of left to right?  I will change the accepted the answer if you don't mind posting something.

Comment: @William https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111413/how-are-urls-with-right-to-left-tlds-represented don't think I can explain it better, so go through the links

Comment: @pun I believe you misunderstood my question.  Does the url bar switch from going from left to right to right to left when in the address bar.  I didn't read the entire w3 standard but I don't think either had what I was talking about.  Let me reread them again.  The standard that they are interpreted in is different then what you are asking.

Comment: @William **NO**, it doesn't change